# Make FireMonkey TListBox in XE5 transparent

Tags: delphi, transparent, firemonkey, tlistbox

I have done some FireMonkey stuff in XE2, in this case I'm having troubles with a customized TListBox.

In XE2 I built this customized TListBox by removing it's background and surrounding rectangle (basically I only need the 'grouping of child items' functionality provided by TListBox. This was simple, drop a TListBox, hit 'edit custom style', select the background rectangle, edit the fill and the stroke and you're golden.

Now we're moving to XE5 and I cannot reproduce the same behavior. Using the style book editor I can see the background (which is now TStyleObject and not TRectangle), but I cannot make the changes I could make before. I see tutorials on how to add stuff to a TListBox, but not on how to take default behavior away.

Can someone explain how to achieve this specific behavior, or point me towards a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `StyleLookup` property of the list box to `transparentlistboxstyle`

Comment: Thanks Chris, that helped indeed. Can you explain how and why this works? Where is transparentlistboxstyle defined?

Comment: Same as XE2 ultimately, i.e., it's just another style defined in the default 'platform' style sets - in fact, IIRC, it was actually available in XE2 too, since it's the style used for the embedded list box of a combo box control. That said, since XE2, multiple styles being defined for the same control type is a lot more common - e.g., it's how the framework supplies different standard glyphs for speed buttons, for better or for worse.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think I don't really like some of the black boxness which FireMonkey seem to bring, but apparently it is what it is :)